# Mock a class used as property of a service

Tags: angular, testing, ionic-framework, mocking

I am actually developing an Ionic application. In this context, I implemented an `AlertService` class which has the two following properties:

```
messageAlert: Alert;
errorAlert: Alert;
```

The `Alert` class is the one of the Ionic framework so I don't have any control on it. My idea was to mock the `Alert` class by a homemade mock like the following class:

```
class AlertMock {
    opts:       Object;
    presented:  boolean;

    constructor(opts) {
        this.opts       = opts;
        this.presented  = false;
    }

    present() {
        this.presented  = true;
    }

    dismiss() {
        this.presented  = false;
    }
}
```

It will allow me to simply test the alert state by checking the value of the `presented` property.

But how can I indicate to my `AlertService` that it two `Alert` properties are of type `AlertMock` instead? I don't know if it is even possible. But it seems to me quite basic to be able to mock class like that. Every topic I found talk about mocking service. With DI, it's very simple to replace a type by another, but is there any mechanism to do it with simple class like `Alert` of the Ionic framework?

Comment: make `AlertMock` extend `Alert` and then where you have `messageAlert: Alert;
errorAlert: Alert;` substitute `messageAlert: AlertMock;
errorAlert: AlertMock;`

Answer (score 0):

Import and extend `Alert` in `AlertMock` :

```
import { Alert } from ...

class AlertMock extends Alert {
    opts:       Object;
    presented:  boolean;

    constructor(opts) {
        this.opts       = opts;
        this.presented  = false;
    }

    present() {
        this.presented  = true;
    }

    dismiss() {
        this.presented  = false;
    }
}
```

In your `AlertService`:

```
import { AlertMock } from ...

...

messageAlert: AlertMock;
errorAlert: AlertMock;
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want my `AlertService` to use the `AlertMock` class outside the test part. And I don't want to have all the complexity of the Ionic class in my test.

Comment: hmm i dunno...if u want to change the `Alert` to have the functions of your mock, i think you have to extend it and use it in your service

Comment: So there isn't any mechanism with `TestBed` for example which would allow me to say something like: I want to use `ClassA` instead of `ClassB`? As we would do with DI for example.

Comment: oh i was a little hazy on your testing situation...im not sure if it is or not